# Question about how to solve an inseperable differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In my differential equations class we are discussing how to find the amount of salt at a specific time given the rate of change equation $$\frac{dS}{dT} = 2-\frac{S}{(15+T)}$$ where $T$ is time and $S$ is the amount of salt.  I had the idea to attempt to rewrite the equation so that we can take the integral of each part of the equation.  I encountered a problem where $T$ didn't always align with the $dT$ and similar for $S$. I decided to partially integrate, similar to taking a partial derivative and got an answer that seemed right.  I want to know if it is viable to use this method to solve an inseparable equation or if I would need to use other methods in order to arrive at the correct answer.

Comment: Please be sure to edit your questions for grammar and spelling, and in the future to use MathJaX formatting. I have done the edits for you, and they will be visible after moderator approval.

Answer (score 0):

Just separation of variables will not suffice, but you will use it at one point.

When i encounter a new differential equation, the first thing i think about is its type (like linear, nonlinear, autonomous, homogeneous, etc). So think about what type your equation is and what methods apply.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly apply separation of variables.

This is a **first-order linear ordinary differential equation**:
$$\frac{dS}{dT}+f(T)S=g(T)$$
Put your equation in the form above:
$$\frac{dS}{dT}+\frac{1}{15+T}S=2 \tag{1}$$
You can solve this using an [Integrating factor](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx) or by using [Variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters).

For this example, I will use the integrating factor method.

The integrating factor will be given by: $\mu(T)=e^{\int \frac{1}{T+15}~dT}=T+15$. No need to consider the arbitrary constant of integration.

Therefore, we multiply this by $\mu(T)$ (Our integrating factor) on both sides of $(1)$:
$$(T+15)\frac{dS}{dT}+S=2(T+15)\tag{2}$$
Now, substitute $1=\frac{d}{dT}(T+15)$:
$$(T+15)\frac{dS}{dT}+\frac{d(T+15)}{dT}S=2(T+15)\tag{3}$$
And use the reverse chain rule on the LHS of equation $(3)$: $uv'+v'u=(uv)'$. Then integrate both sides with respect to $T$.

Feel free to ask questions if you cannot continue from here.